# QtWidgets.QLabel добавление метки в цикле

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qlayout

Помогите разобраться! Есть форма, в нее надо вставить **`N`** - кол-во меток столбцом.

Пример делаю, но что-то не так.

---

```
self.siz = 30
self.lab = 0
for row_ip in cursor.fetchall():  # тут лезем в базу и берем данные
    self.ip = row_ip[1]
self.siz = self.siz + 10 # прибавляем изменение высоты на 10
self.lab = self.lab + 1  # метка+1

self.lab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.lab.setFont(font)
self.lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, self.siz, 295, 20))
self.lab.setText(self.ip)
```

---

как правильно сделать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # какие-то данные
        cursorFetchall = [ ["item0", "ip0"], ["item1", "ip1"], ["item2", "ip2"], ["item3", "ip3"], ]

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget) 

        layout = QFormLayout(centralWidget)  

        for record in cursorFetchall:                            # тут лезем в базу и берем данные
            name = record[0]
            ip   = record[1]   

            layout.addRow(QLabel("{}: ".format(name)), QLabel(ip))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да это хороший пример НО тут не возможно учитывать размер между строками

Comment: self.label.lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, siz, 295, 20)) где siz как раз размер от предыдущего

Answer (score 0):

```
siz = 30
        lab = 0
        for row_ip in cursor.fetchall():
            self.ip_host = row_ip[1]
siz = siz + 10
            lab = lab + 1
            self.label.lab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.label.lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, siz, 295, 20))
            self.label.lab.setText(self.ip_host + "   " + self.ip_tip)
```

Comment: ну вообщем из цыкал рано вышел - решение сверху

Comment: Вы применяете абсолютное позиционирование, указывает позицию и размер каждого виджета в пикселях. 
При использовании абсолютного позиционирования, у нас есть следующие ограничения:
Размеры и позиция виджета не меняются, если мы меняем размер окна; 
Приложения могут выглядеть по-разному на разных платформах; 
Изменение шрифтов в нашем приложении может испортить макет; 
Если мы решаем изменить наш макет, мы должны полностью переделать его, что утомительно и занимает много времени. 

И рано и поздно поймете, что лучше работать с макетами.